# z-index not working on child div with position absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-shapes

i am trying to create a ribbon where triangle div should be placed below its 
      
        Cart 
         
      parent div

```
<div class="rectangle">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu font_Size_12" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1" style="min-width: 100px; z-index: 0">
    <li role="presentation">
       <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sign in </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation">
       <a rolw="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">View Cart</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <!-- Ribbon side-fold (left and right) -->
  <div class="triangle-l triangle-left-pos"></div>
  <div class="triangle-r triangle-right-pos"></div>
</div>
```

and [JS Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/814nf0kw/)
so my problem is the , child div is not getting placed under the parent div, in the fiddle, the div is placed above, though i have given the z-index lesser than the parent div.

Edit :- Adding image, where the child div should be placed

[image: ribbon image]

Comment: The arrows has to appear below the cart button and above the two links?

Comment: the arrow should appear below the cart and the two links

Comment: this could be achieved with a single element with a pseudo element. [Some help here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcss-shapes%5D+ribbon)

Comment: your [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/814nf0kw/3/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Stacking contexts are treated atomically as a single unit in the parent stacking context.

The parent element `.rectangle` has created a stacking context, so the children elements' `z-index` were resolved within `.rectangle`, thus they cannot be placed under their parent.

If you move the `z-index` property of `.rectangle` element, and apply negative `z-index` value to the children then they can be placed as you wished. Because in this case, both the parent element and children elements are belonging to a same stacking context(#root in your demo), and negative `z-index` order let children stay lower than parent in the Z axis.

But remember, if you apply a CSS3 transform, or make an opacity transition of the parent element, a new stacking context will be created and it will be rendered same as what you get in your demo.

Ref: [The stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/814nf0kw/1/) ?

Then get rid of the `top` values from `.triangle-left-pos and` and `triangle-left-pos`.

Comment: it should get placed below the parent div on either corner side, so it should look like a ribbon. let me add an image

Comment: That would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you doing as of now is not possible until unless you will not change your HTML markup.

> Please see the documentation for CSS Position
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

but what result you are trying to achieve is not impossible please check the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/nileshmahaja/7coznt7o/

**HTML**

```
<div class="rectangle-wrap">
<div class="rectangle">
                            <h2 class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                Cart <i class="icon-shopping-cart"></i> <b class="caret"></b>
                            </h2>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu font_Size_12" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1" style="min-width: 100px; z-index: 0">
                                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Sign in </a></li>
                                <li role="presentation"><a rolw="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">View Cart</a></li>
                            </ul>
    <!-- Ribbon side-fold (left and right) -->
                        </div></div>
```

**css**

```
.rectangle-wrap{
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    height:32px;
}
.rectangle {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #de8a03;
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height: 32px;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}


.rectangle  h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.rectangle-wrap:before {
    border-color: transparent #332619 transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    left:-10px;
    bottom:-10px;
}


.rectangle-wrap:after {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #332619;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:-10px;
    top:-10px;
    z-index:0
}
```